# Populate the HTML form fields from mysql database on selecting dropdown option

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to populate the text fields from the database based on particular option is selected in the dropdown. e.g dropdown contains the titles of the articles and when i select or click on certain article such that "science" then the content from the database against science should be shown in the textarea in the form...
please.......
Any thing will be appreciated :)

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: You need AJAX to accomplish that. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example of retrieving info using ajax: (this uses jQuery)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <select id="myselect">
      <option>---</option>
      <option>Milk</option>
      <option>Coffee</option>
      <option>Tea</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <textarea id="result"></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#myselect').change(function()
        {
            var selected = $(this).find(':selected').html();
            $.post('http://localhost/tests/ajax.php', {'beverage': selected}, function(data) {
              $('#result').html(data);
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is your ajax.php file (change the code to retrieve information from the database).

```
if (isset($_POST['beverage']))
{
    switch($_POST['beverage'])
    {
        case 'Milk':
            print 'Milk makes you grow!';
            break;
        case 'Coffee':
            print 'Coffee does not let you sleep!';
            break;
        case 'Tea':
            print 'Tea comes from China!';
            break;
        default:
            print 'Nothing was selected';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to accomplish it :

First, PHP  without ajax way: There should be two forms ..one with the the first drop down which contains the  data pre-populated from db...Once user submits this form (i.e javascript submit or traditional submit button click) that data can be evaluated against content of query statements by passing this as a value ...
Data returned from the SELECT statement is then re-displayed in the textarea of another form on the same page..

Second,Use ajax to do the POST instead of using the two form approach that will be faster and more efficient..

Comment: ok thanks! but would you explain that how it will work with the dropdown option???

Comment: <form name="frm1"><select name="ddl">....</select></forn>
//php code
if(isset($_POST['ddl']) || !empty($_POST['ddl']))
{}